# Quarkus - Package application to an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, quarkus

We were on the process to upgrade our existing Quarkus application from version 2.16.3 to 3.0.3. The application is build so that it can be deployed as an Azure Function. The issue is that an uber-jar is no longer created. It seems that the issue is caused by the following Maven dependency which did work in version 2.16.3.Final:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-azure-functions-http</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Even when I explicitly set the packaging to type 'uber-jar', nothing changes. Is this a known issue or is there a different implementation path?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you open an issue on the Quarkus Github repo please?

Comment: Posted issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33525